# Authorize.net not recording processor fees

Tags: civicontribute, payment-processor, authorize.net

I noticed today that Authorize.net is not recording the payment processor fees. Is there a way to get the civiCRM payment processor to record such a fee so that we can record the data? I have found some information for paypal, but nothing for Authorize.net

I found this odd since the Authorize.Net is a core supported payment processor.

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.Net doesn't return this information, which is why it's not available in CiviCRM.

One of the fields returned in the [PayPal API documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#transaction-object) is `transaction_fee`. [Authorize.Net's API documentation](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html) has no equivalent in the "Response" section.

The reason is that Authorize.Net *can't* tell you the transaction fee based on a single transaction, because their calculations are more complicated than PayPal's.  PayPal charges a high amount on every transaction, so they can give you a simple pricing structure.  Authorize.Net gives, e.g., variable rates based on volume, which can't be calculated until your month is over.

Comment: Authorize.net has adopted a similar pricing structure to Paypal's if you use them as a merchant account: http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/pricing/

I have looked through the API and know they don't send transaction data. Is there a way to manually enter this fee amount for every transaction (sort of like a tax?) so that the bank fees can be calculated correctly?

Comment: @Becca You could write a hook to do this - hook_civicrm_pre is probably the right one.